# If rank(A)=rank(B)=n then show that rank(AB)=n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

A and B are square nxn matrices and I'm asked to show that if rank(A)=rank(B)=n then rank(AB)=n

I'm aware this is likely quite simple, but I can't seem to figure how to start the proof for some reason. I would greatly appreciate any help. If you do find how, please try to do so only using very basic theorems about rank. This is a potential exam question and I'm not sure which theorems she'll allow us to just know or claim we have to show.

Also, I know it's very looked down upon to post a question that you haven't at least tried, but I genuinely don't know how to even start this. My first thought was to think about row equivalent matrices and showing that if this is true for A and B in reduced row echelon form, then it must be for the non-reduced A and B. But I'm not sure how to show that and it seems overly complex to begin with.

Note that I was taught the definition of rank to be the dimension of the row space. And also note that, through some trivial connections, rank(A)=n very clearly makes the invertible matrix theorem useful. This probably makes the problem even simpler.

Comment: $A, B$ are full rank and only have the trivial kernel.  Suppose $AB$ was not full rank, then $AB$ has a non-trivial kernel.   Let $v$ be in the kernel of $AB.$  But what does $Bv$ look like?  and what about $A(Bv)$?  You will arrive at a contradiction.  Alternatively, consider $\det(A), \det(B)$ and $\det(AB)$.

Comment: Which definition of the rank where you taught? And what theorem(s) about it? Please do not answer as a comment but add it to your post.

Comment: I don't know if I would have marked this a duplicate, as the answer I would give here wouldn't be the answer I give there, but copper.hat's answer in the linked question is very close to answering your question.  In particular, if you reverse the order of the multiplication there, it will give you a proof of your problem from first principles.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to go I to note that $\operatorname{rank} M=n\iff\det M\neq 0$ for and $n\times n$ matrix.

Now, let $M,N$ be of rank $n$. Then:

$\det(M.N)=\det(M).\det(N)\neq 0$ by hypothesis since $\operatorname{rank} M=\operatorname{rank} N=n$

Since $\det(M.N)\neq 0$ one has that $\operatorname{rank}(M.N)=n$

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer (among other ones) is contained in the duplicate. It is better not to duplicate answers to duplicate questions.

Comment: Oh I didn't know sorry I just answered. Should I remove it? Also how can one know if an answer is duplicate?

Comment: No trouble. I think so. If you mean how can one *find* a duplicate (like the one in the comment above): either by using key words in a search query on this site, or by typing a formula on https://approach0.xyz/